# Executing system commands safely while coding in Perl

Tags: perl, security

Should one really use external commands while coding in Perl? I see several disadvantages of it. It's not system independent plus security risks might also be there. What do you think? If there is no way and you have to use the shell commands from Perl then what is the safest way to execute that particular command (like checking pid, uid etc)?

Comment: Basically I think: If your program allows do do non-intended nonsense, it's irrelevant whether that nonsense is done using built-in functions or external commands (processes). Sometimes external programs may protect you from doing nonsense more than your own code does, sometimes they make it easier to do nonsense. Probably the key to all is: "*Know what you are doing!*"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how hard it is going to be to replicate the functionality in Perl.  If I needed to run the `m4` macro processor on something, I'd not think of trying to replicate that functionality in Perl myself, and since there's no module on http://search.cpan.org/ that looks suitable, it would appear others agree with me.  In that case, then, using the external program is sensible.  On the other hand, if I needed to read the contents of a directory, then the combination of `readdir()` et al plus `stat()` or `lstat()` inside Perl is more sensible than futzing with the output of `ls`.

If you need to execute commands, think very carefully about how you invoke them.  In particular, you probably want to avoid the shell interpreting the arguments, so use the array form of [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) (see also [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html)), etc, rather than a single string for the command plus arguments (which means the shell is used to process the command line).

Answer (score 3):

Executing external commands can be expensive simply because it involves forking new process and watching for its output if you need it.

Probably more importantly, should external process fail for any reason, it may be difficult to understand what happened by means of your script. Worse still, surprisingly often external process can be stuck forever,  so will be your script. You can use special tricks like opening pipe and watching for output in loop, but this itself is error-prone.

Perl is very capable of doing many things. So, if you stick to using only Perl native constructs and modules to accomplish your tasks, not only it will be faster because you never fork, but it will be more reliable and easier to catch errors by looking at native Perl objects and structures returned by library routines. And of course, it will be automatically portable to different platforms.

If your script runs under elevated permissions (like root or under sudo), you should be very careful as to what external programs you execute. One of the simple ways to ensure basic security is to always specify commands by full name, like /usr/bin/grep (but still think twice and just do grep by Perl itself!). However, even this may not be enough if attacker is using LD_PRELOAD mechanism to inject rogue shared libraries.

If you are willing to go very secure, it is suggested to use tainted check by using -T flag like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
```

Taint flag will be also enabled by Perl automatically if your script was determined to have different real and effective user or group ids.

Tainted mode will severely limit your ability to do many things (like system() call) without Perl complaining - see more at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode, but it will give you much higher security confidence.

Comment: Yes Taint mode will be more strict and secure way.

Answer (score 1):

> Should one really use external commands while coding in Perl?

There's no single answer to this question.  It all depends on what you are doing within the wide range of potential uses of Perl.

Are you using Perl as a glorified shell script on your local machine, or just trying to find a quick-and-dirty solution to your problem?  In that case, it makes a lot of sense to run system commands if that is the easiest way to accomplish your task.  Security and speed are not that important; what matters is the ability to code quickly.

On the other hand, are you writing a production program?  In that case, you want secure, portable, efficient code.  It is often preferable to write the functionality in Perl (or use a module), rather than calling an external program.  At least, you should think hard about the benefits and drawbacks.